# How to replace certain rows in a dataframe based off of values in another dataframe while preserving order using R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'Total: AB', 'C', 'D', 'Total: CD'),
  Value1 = c(12, 88, 100, 76, 23, 99),
  Value2 = c(10, 82, 92, 71, 21, 92)
)
```

And another that looks like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'Total: AB', 'C', 'D', 'Total: CD'),
  Value1 = c(435, 568, 1003, 709, 183, 727),
  Value2 = c(180, 370, 550, 199, 283, 482)
)
```

I want to replace the `Total` rows in `df1` with their values in `df2` for a result like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Group = c('A', 'B', 'Total: AB', 'C', 'D', 'Total: CD'),
  Value1 = c(12, 88, 1003, 76, 23, 727),
  Value2 = c(10, 82, 550, 71, 21, 482)
)
```

What's the best way to do this while preserving row order using R, ideally `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datasets are in order and have the same dimensions, find the locations of 'Total' substring from the 'Group' column in 'df1' and use that as row index to replace the values other than the first column in 'df1' with the corresponding values from 'df2'

```
df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)
df2 <- type.convert(df2, as.is = TRUE)
i1 <- grep("Total", df1$Group)
df1[i1, -1] <- df2[i1, -1]
```

-checking

```
> identical(df1, df_desired)
[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df3 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with("Value"), ~ 
      case_when(str_detect(Group, 'Total') ~ df2[[cur_column()]], 
      TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
df3
      Group Value1 Value2
1         A     12     10
2         B     88     82
3 Total: AB   1003    550
4         C     76     71
5         D     23     21
6 Total: CD    727    482
```

Comment: This is great. My df is full of factors which gets overwritten using this method. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Yes the columns in df1 and df2 are all of factor class. So when I run your code above it does the replacement but it makes all the non-replaced rows (A, B, C, D above) into NAs. I get the “Invalid factor level, NA generated” warning.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: What if the dimensions of the dataframe are different? E.g., df1 is twice as large due to extra rows while df2 is the same size. Is there a good way to edit the `case_when` to account for this?

Comment: @NatashaR. `case_when` or `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same length.  If there is length difference, there should be some other info to match i.e. doing a join etc.